# Saving data from DynamoDB locally on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to android as well as to AWS.
I have a java program which reads articles from some websites and store information (like title,link,description,date...) in a dynamoDB on AWS.

Now, I want to develop an Android application that will read the data. I guess that reading the data from the server each time the app starts would be wasteful, so I think I should save the data locally and just download updates from the DB whenever there are new entries. (I just add item to db, never update or something).

My question is what is the best way for doing this?

1. how can I sync data from dynamoDB only when there are new entries?
2. is sqlite is the best way to store this kind of data in android?

If there is another way of doing the same I'm open to learn.

Thank you.

Comment: How do would you know there are new entries without querying the database?

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for you comment. So you say that every time the user open the app I have to query both database(the one on the server and the one locally on the phone) and see if they are the same? Is there a way doing that smarter?

Comment: That's what I'm asking you. What is your plan to determine when new items have been inserted into DynamoDB? Your question makes it sound like you have that figured out already. If you don't, then querying DynamoDB to see if you should query DynamoDB is going to defeat the purpose of your optimization.

Comment: Sorry but I'm little bit confused. My question is what is the optimum way to query the database on the server only when the local database is out of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. how can I sync data from dynamoDB only when there are new entries?

You could possibly put some sort of settings file on the internet (perhaps on S3) for your Android app to check each time it opens. This file could contain the ID or timestamp of the last record inserted into DynamoDB. Your android app could then compare that to the local version to determine if it needs to pull updates from DynamoDB.

This is still a call out to the internet though. Depending on how much data you are storing in DynamoDB it might be just as fast to query DynamoDB directly every time. This would also add complexity to your data update process, requiring you to ensure that the file on S3 always gets updated.

> 2. is sqlite is the best way to store this kind of data in android?

Yes that seems like the best place, although without knowing more about the amount and type of data you are storing it's hard to make a definitive recommendation.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I'll do something similar but little different. I'll save the last id (which increase by one) on the device and then query just for this id and newer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides [Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/synchronizing-data.html) for synchronizing local data with the sync store.

> The synchronize method compares local cached data to the data stored
>   in the Amazon Cognito Sync store. Remote changes are pulled from the
>   Amazon Cognito Sync store; conflict resolution is invoked if any
>   conflicts occur; and updated values on the device are pushed to the
>   service.

It is not totally clear though if the sync store is a DynamoDB database. This [link](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/) says:

> The Amazon Cognito Sync store is a key/value pair store linked to an
>   Amazon Cognito identity.

Comment: @morgul, Since this is not a 100% bullet-proof answer, should I delete it? Thanks,